# MongoDB - Adding db and collection level roles to user

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

It's been few hours that I dived into MongoDB.
I can't figure out particular set of roles/privileges (need to know the diff too)

Here's my problem:

given a database `db_xyz`

User `ABCD` can;

1. create one or more collection
2. read/write/update/remove/find access only to collections created by `ABCD`
3. can drop the collections created by `ABCD`
4. CAN'T IN ANY WAY ACCESS OTHER COLLECTIONS IN db_xyz OR PERFORM ANY OTHER OP.

I am going to be doing mixture of these ops via Mongo prompt and using pymongo.

Answer (score 5):

MongoDB allows us to create ["User Defined Roles"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-user-defined-roles/), using `db.createRole()`, for more information on `db.createRole()` [see here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createRole/#db.createRole)

The below code is to create a role named role_1 with read/write/update/remove/find options

```
use db_xyz
db.createRole(
   {
     role: "role_1",
     privileges: [
       { resource: { db: "db_xyz", collection: "" }, actions: [ "find", "update", "insert", "remove" ] },
     ],
     roles: []
   }
)
```

After creating the Role use `db.grantRolesToUser()` more info on `db.grantRolesToUser()` [see here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.grantRolesToUser/#db.grantRolesToUser)

Code shown below is to assign the newly created role_1 to our user ABCD

```
use db_xyz
db.grantRolesToUser(
    "ABCD",
    [
      { role: "role_1", db: "db_xyz" }
    ]
)
```